# React-boostrap form fields render side by side instead of one beneath the other

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-bootstrap

I am using react-bootstrap to create a form. The title, datePicker, and dropdown do appear how I want them to, on the same row with space in between them, but when I try to insert a text-area underneath those fields, it renders next to the dropdown menu instead. What is the problem?

```
<Form>
           <Form.Row>
                <Form.Group as={Col}>
                <Form.Control name="title"
                    type="title"
                    placeholder="Enter title"
                    value={this.state.title}
                    onChange={e => this.change(e)}  
                />
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group as={Col}>
                    <DatePicker
                        selected={this.state.startDate}
                        onChange={e => this.change(e)}
                    />
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group as={Col}>
                    <select className="custom-select" name="course" value={this.state.course} onChange={e => this.change(e)}>
                        <option value="Math234">Math234</option>
                        <option value="Art">Art</option>
                    </select>
                </Form.Group>
            </Form.Row>

            <Form.Group>
                <Form.Label>Enter notes</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control 
                        name = "notes"
                        as="textarea" 
                        rows="3" 
                        value={this.state.notes}
                        onChange={e => this.change(e)}
                    />
            </Form.Group>
        </Form>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to define each `Col`'s size. The bootstrap cols are rendering side by side if you do not tell them the axact size for each breakpoint, or at least one. In this case, your `Form.Group` will get the `col` and all the other column related classnames.

Try out something like this:

```
<Form.Row>
  <Form.Group as={Col} sm={12}>
    {/* your form control goes here */}
  </Form.Group>
</Form.Row>
```

The `xs`, `sm`, `md` and `lg` breakpoint props are all available in this case, use them as you wish.